# In IE after login dialog, focus is not on page again

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10, visual-studio-2012

As developer, using VS2012 and IE10, when a login dialog pops up, entering username & password and pressing OK or enter, the focus is not given on the page, but on VS2012.

How can this be disabled ? It is very annoying to manually focus on the page every time I logged in.

Comment: webbrowser1.Document.GetElementById("webpage_tag").Focus()

Comment: It has nothing to do with the page, but with ie, my collegue doesn't have this issue